# Unhandled exception details in Glassfish

Tags: jsp, exception, servlets, glassfish, unhandled

I would like to see the exception details when an unhandled exception thrown in Glassfish (In the web page, not logs).

This error page shows but there's no useful information. Is there an option to view more details of it when an exception thrown? (*Like in asp.net if you make debugmode true in web.config you can see the exception details*)

> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an
>   internal error () that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException note
>   The full stack traces of the exception
>   and its root causes are available in
>   the Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1 logs.
>
> Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you should do things like that only in development environments as it publishes internal application details to the outside world (security issue). Nevertheless, you can define a generic exception jsp in your web.xml:

```
<web-app>
     <error-page>
         <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
         <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/throwable.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

The `throwable.jsp`'s page element must contain an `isErrorPage` attribute:

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
```

This attribute defines the variable **exception** of type `java.lang.Throwable`, so you can examine your exception inside `throwable.jsp`:

```
<div style="font-family: monospace">
    <pre>
<% exception.printStackTrace(new java.io.PrintWriter(pageContext.getOut())); %>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that was what I looking for. But one more question, I don't have a web.xml, but I have a sun-web.xml. Are they same?

Comment: They definitely are not. You should have ticked the *Generate deployment descriptor?* checkbox during Eclipse project creation wizard to get one. Now you need to manually create one.